# Get multiple field id when using paragraphs

Tags: 8, paragraphs

I created a paragraph (machine name `date`) with 2 fields (`date_1` and `date_2`). When adding this paragraph (Entity Reference `field_date`) to my content type `Agenda` I choose the 'Allowed number of values: unlimited' option.

I create a node for content type `Agenda` with multiple fields of the `field_date` field.

Now I'm changing the output of the fields of the paragraphs in a `paragraph--date.html.twig` template. But I want to know/track in this template if there is a multiple field and for example if it is the first or the last value.

How is this possible?

Comment: When you want to keep track of multiple value fields, for example add classes to the first and last value, then use a field template like `field--node--field-date--agenda.html.twig`

Comment: Thanks, but I need to have this info in the paragraph template mentioned, not in the field template. Any suggestions for that?

Comment: There is no straightforward way, because entities in an entity reference field are unaware of where they are rendered and this can change without that the rendered entity is invalidated.

Comment: Ah to bad. Since there is no neat way to fix this I solved it by creating two extra hidden fields to the paragraph one for the current position and one of the total number of fields. With a little jQuery it's easy to fill these out so I can read this information in my paragraph template.

Comment: jQuery is a good hint, although most times CSS with multiple selectors should do it.